# Speed up spatial query on large table on psql

Tags: postgis, query, optimization

How to speed up spatial query on large table of bytea.

I tried the [suggestion from this website](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-1.3/ch03.html#id434676) to create an index using b-tree GIST but the index is exceed the maximum size of 8191. 
Any suggestions?

Comment: It is a bit hard to tell from this information. What does you query and table structure look like?

Answer (score 1):

A few things

- [b-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree) and [GiST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GiST) are different. And since there isn't a GiST index for `bytea`, then you were probably attempting to build a b-tree on a bytea which will not work.
- PostGIS has two spatial types: `geometry` and `geography`. They can be cast to and from `bytea`.

Perhaps you have a table that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
    id integer primary key,
    geom bytea
);
```

The fix is to alter the table type to `geometry`, e.g.:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table
  ALTER COLUMN geom TYPE geometry;
```

Or specify the geometry type and SRID with a typmod, e.g.:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table
  ALTER COLUMN geom TYPE geometry(Point,4326);
```

Then create a GiST spatial index:

```
CREATE INDEX my_table_geom_idx
  ON my_table
  USING gist(geom);
```

And if you make big changes to the table, it's a good idea to tune the index with this:

```
ANALYZE my_table;
```

(this happens automatically, but it might not do it immediately).